# Set minutes for maintenance window in Windows Server 2012?

Tags: windows-server-2012

The current dialogs only allow setting the automatic maintenance window on the hour. My server needs to run unattended polling tasks on the hour as well.

I'm not opposed to allowing auto reboots but I can't use the feature if it happens on the hour.

How can I configure a window time of say 3:20AM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following command as an elevated administrator:

```
schtasks.exe /change /TN "\Microsoft\Windows\TaskScheduler\Regular Maintenance" /ST 03:20
```

Background activities are implemented either as Windows services or scheduled tasks. This command changes the start time of the task responsible for the `Automatic Maintenance` in the Action Center.

Answer (score 1):

You can define it by using XML.

```
 <!-- DailySchedule -->
<xs:complexType name="dailyScheduleType">
    <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="DaysInterval" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:unsignedInt">
                    <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
                    <xs:maxInclusive value="365"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
```

[Task Scheduler Schema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa383609%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

[Automatic Maintenance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh848037%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will stick over time but...

In Task Scheduler app find the Regular Maintenance task, Double click (Properties) and on the Triggers tab use Edit to change the time.

Location in  tree: Task Scheduler(Local), Task Scheduler Library, Microsoft, Windows, Task Scheduler  (probably a shorter way here, but...)